# ADLS ConcurrentAppend giving corrupt data for 1 MB files

Tags: c#, concurrency, task-parallel-library, azure-data-lake, parallel.for

When I use `Parallel.For` loop to append 10 files of 1 MB size concurrently to Azure Data Lake Service, I only see the content of last 2 files on my Azure Data Lake file, although I see the correct data getting printed to console.

When I use a simple for loop instead of this `Parallel.For`, data getting appended to file is correct.

Any help ?

```
Parallel.For(0, 10, i =>
{
    path[i] = @"C:\Users\t-chkum\Desktop\InputFiles\1MB\" + (i + 1) + ".txt";

    FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(path[i]);

    stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer));


    client.ConcurrentAppend(fileName, true, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    stream.Close();
});
```

Comment: Are you using ADLS gen1 or gen2? And which sdk(and it's version) are you using?

Comment: I am using Gen1 , and  .NET sdk ( version 3.1.100)

Comment: Moreover , i tried printing data to console, when i print it before Calling concurrentAppend API , i see content from all files , but when i print it to console , after calling concurrentAppend -> only last files content is shown on console.

Comment: Got it. I'll take a look tomorrow.

Comment: hey ! I figured it out. It was a critical section while i was reading to buffer

Comment: Great! Could you please post an answer with your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually a critical section problem and can be solve using either block collections or lock :

```
BlockingCollection<int> b = new BlockingCollection<int>(1);
Parallel.For(0, 10, i =>
{
    b.Add(i);
    path[i] = @"C:\Users\t-chkum\Desktop\InputFiles\1MB\" + (i + 1) + ".txt";
    FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(path[i]);

    stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    client.ConcurrentAppend(fileName, true, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    stream.Close();
    b.Take();
});
```

The above code solves the problem for me :)